# Integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x} + \sqrt{\cos x}} dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, radicals

We have to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x} + \sqrt{\cos x}} dx$$

I tried this:

I multiplied both the numerator and denominator by $\sec x$
And substituted $\tan x = t$.

But after that I got stuck.

The book where this is taken from gives the following as the answer: $$\ln(1+t)-\frac14\ln(1+t^4)+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\ln\frac{t^2-\sqrt2t+1}{t^2+\sqrt2t+1}-\frac12\tan^{-1}t^2+c$$ where $t=\sqrt{\cot x}$

Comment: Are you sure it is not a definite integral?

Comment: @Rohan It doesn't have limits, so it must be indefinite

Comment: The indefinite integral is not nice to calculate, the answer if far too large, and involves many elliptic functions. 
Even Wolfram alpha won't calculate it:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28sqrt%28sin%28x%29%29+%2F%28+sqrt%28sin%28x%29%29+%2B+sqrt%28cos%28x%29%29%29%29+dx+

Comment: It's possible with elementary functions.

Comment: @Rohan the answer given in my book as http://i.imgur.com/qHhVFpe.jpg

Comment: And if it's a definite integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then it is a very popular question and already has an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167409/evaluating-displaystyle-int-0-frac-pi2-frac-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-s) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530779/integral-of-int-0-pi-2-frac-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-cos-x)

Comment: @SakethMalyala how ?

Comment: See also [Evaluation of $ \int\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/875014). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Ccos%20x%7D%7D%20dx%24&p=1).

Comment: Just a note: plugging in the value $t = \sqrt{\cot x}$ into the final answer and using some trig identities can simplify some terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\displaystyle \mathcal{I} = \int\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$

substitute $\tan x= t^2$ and $\displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{1+t^4}dt$

$\displaystyle \mathcal{I}= \int\frac{t}{(1+t)(1+t^4)}dt = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\bigg((1+t^4)+(1-t^4)\bigg)t}{(1+t)(1+t^4)}dt$

$\displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t}{1+t}dt+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(t-t^2)(1+t^2)}{1+t^4}dt$

$\displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{(1+t)-1}{1+t}dt+\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{t+t^3-(t^2-1)-t^4-1}{1+t^4}dt$

$\displaystyle =-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln|t+1|+\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{2t}{1+t^4}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}dt-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{t^2-1}{1+t^4}dt-\frac{1}{2}t+\mathcal{C}$

all integrals are easy except $\displaystyle \mathcal{J} = \int\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^4}dt = \int\frac{1-t^{-2}}{\left(t+t^{-1}\right)^2-2}dt = \int\frac{(t-t^{-1})'}{(t-t^{-1})^2-2}dt$

Comment: if we substitute $\tan x= t^2$ then $\displaystyle dx = \frac{2t}{1+t^4}dt$

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{2t^2}{(1+t)(1+t^4)}$ when $\tan x = t^2$? I think you used $\cot x = t^2$ (an answer by @openspace below).

Answer (score 5):

We rationalise the denominator to get $$I =\int \frac {\sin x-\sqrt {\cos x\sin x}}{\sin x-\cos x} dx $$ Writing everything in terms of $\cot x $, we get $$I =\int \mathrm{csc}^2 x\left(\frac {\sqrt {\cot x}-1}{\cot^3 x-\cot^2 x+\cot x-1}\right) dx $$ Now substituting $u=\cot x $ and further $v=\sqrt {u} $ gives us $$I = -\int\frac {2v }{v^5+ v^4 + v+1} dv $$ Performing a partial fraction decomposition we have $$I = \frac {2}{4-4\sqrt {2}}\int \frac {v +\sqrt {2}-1}{v^2 +\sqrt {2}v +1} dv  +\frac {2}{4+4\sqrt {2}}\int \frac {v-\sqrt {2}-1}{v^2-\sqrt {2 }v+1} dv+\int \frac {1}{1+v} dv =I_1 +I_2 +I_3$$ Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 4):

*HINT* multiply nominator and denominator by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{sin(x)}}$, then $t = \sqrt{cot(x)} $ after all you'll have $\displaystyle\frac{2t}{(t^4 + 1)(t+1)}$

Comment: After that does we have to substitue t = sin k

Comment: @koolman I have no this substitution in my hint.

Comment: I mean what we have to after$\displaystyle\frac{2t}{(t^4 + 1)(t+1)}$

Comment: @koolman we could represent this as sum of polynomials with denominators $t^4 + 1$ and $t + 1$

Answer (score -1):

$$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\;=\;\int\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\cot x}},\\  
\displaystyle\cot x=z^{2} \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; -(1+z^{2})dx=2zdz,\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\cot x}} \;=\; -\int\frac{2zdz}{(1+z^{2})(1+z)} \;=\; -2\int\frac{z(z-1)dz}{z^{4}-1}.\\
\displaystyle\frac{z}{z^{4}-1}\;=\;\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{z}{z^{2}-1}-\frac{z}{z^{2}+1} \right),\\
\displaystyle\frac{z^{2}}{z^{4}-1}\;=\;\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z^{2}-1}+\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}),\\
\displaystyle\frac{z^{2}-z}{z^{4}-1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1-z}{z^{2}-1})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}+\frac{z}{z^{2}+1})=-\frac{1}{2(z+1)}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}+\frac{z}{z^{2}+1}).\\
\displaystyle-2\int\frac{z(z-1)dz}{z^{4}-1}\;=\;\ln\left| z+1 \right|-\arctan{z}-\ln\sqrt{z^{2}+1}+c,\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\;=\;\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\cot{x}}+1}{\sqrt{\cot{x}+1}} \right)-\arctan{\sqrt{\cot{x}}}+c.$$

Comment: $-(1+z^{2})dx=2zdz$ is questionable; so is the result